# Using ShopifyQL in web services

Tags: api, server, shopify

Can someone tell me how to query shopify in server? I want to fetch product data by barcode but I don't know where should I put my query in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I can solve it with :

1. get all admin/products.json with limit and page
2. limit and page can be handle with admin/products/count.json (https://www.demacmedia.com/shopify-commerce/shopify-tutorials/how-to-fetch-all-products-using-shopify-pagination/)
3. for make it faster we can use products.json?field=id,barcode,etc
4. then loop the json result with object.find until found the right product with attribute you want to filter

Thanks guys for your answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

At this time, it's only possible to invoke ShopifyQL from the Embedded App SDK.

Comment: Jamie, can you give any insight as to why that is? Requiring developers who want access to the data Shopify already houses to instead receive webhook payloads containing all order data and storing it themselves is considerably less secure than just exposing access to analytics.